# babel-preset-env and stage-0 confusing

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Stages represent the status of experimental features? 
what fetures are on experimental, any links/details of it?

```
  "presets": [
   [ "env",{
    "modules": false,
    "targets": {
      "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"]
    }
    }
  ],
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
   [ "transform-runtime",{
    "helpers": false,
    "polyfill": false,
    "regenerator": true }
  ],
  ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
 ]
}
```

should i include stage-0 or not in above configuration?

Answer (score 0):

https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/

You can see it also includes stage 1, 2 and 3 as well. If you included stage-1 in your project, it would also include 2 and 3 (and not 0).

You can see the list of babel plugins included in each stage preset in the link I pasted and links therein.

stage-0 is most experimental and not generally recommended, but I use stage-1 in several projects. I intend to take it out in the future and include only the specific plugins my projects need, and stay away from class decorators since it is in flux. This notion seems to be the recommended path (from reading babel-present-env issues etc)

Your config looks correct. Go to the highest stage possible based on what you intend to use. You can get away without using any of it, so if you prefer fewer surprises in a year+ then try to get things done without a lower stage.

Answer (score 0):

FOR new **babel7**
about preset **es2015** 
babel-preset-es2015 -> babel-preset-env https://babeljs.io/docs/en/env
about preset **stage-0** 
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-stage-0 (**deprecated**)